# Getting error while inserting value into a table that consist foreign key in .NET and Angular

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I want to add a foreign key to a table. I've added the required columns, but I'm getting an error when I'm trying to pass the value into the table using PostMan.

This is my `JobPosting` entity / table:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

namespace Backend.Model
{
    public class JobPosting
    {
        [Key]
        public int JobId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("HR")]
        public  int? HrId { get; set; }
        public virtual HrRegistration HR{ get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int Experience { get; set; }
        public string Position { get; set; }
        public string Company { get; set; }
        public int Ctc { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is my `HRRegistration` entity:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace Backend.Model
{
    public class HrRegistration
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
        public string Mobile { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }

        public string Company { get; set; }
        public string Post { get; set; }
        public string CTC { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is the method I'm using to insert the data into the table

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost("InsertJobDetails")]
public IActionResult InsertJobDetails(JobPosting job)
{
    job.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    Context.jobPostings.Add(job);
    Context.SaveChanges();

    return Ok(job);
}
```

Below is the error I'm getting

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-f3dbe55093c2de02f7258fc88dc11a4f-d9264da1a2769bd3-00",
    "errors": {
        "HR": [
            "The HR field is required."
        ]
    }
}
```

And here is a screenshot of the error:

[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSqXh.png)

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have `hrid` in your job parameter also context name `hrRegistrations` in your `DataContext` Class. problem is you actually did not Retrieve the corresponding `HrRegistration` entity. update your method like below:-

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost("InsertJobDetails")]
public IActionResult InsertJobDetails(JobPosting job)
{
    job.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
    var hr = Context.hrRegistrations.FirstOrDefault(h => h.Id == job.HrId);

    if (hr == null)
    {
        return BadRequest("Invalid");
    }

    job.HR = hr;  //set hr navigation property
    Context.jobPostings.Add(job);
    Context.SaveChanges();

    return Ok(job);
}
```

Hope it will resolve your issue. if not works let me know.

Comment: Hi Pritom, thanks for suggestions, but unfortunately it's not working, I'm totally clueless to resolve this error, please suggest some alternate method also.

Comment: @AvinashKumar what's your exactly problem right now, clarify that.

Comment: just debug your code, and inform me what properties/values contain you have on your ```job``` parameter. and if your job parameter contain hrid then my given solution will definitely work.

Comment: I'm using the same parameters I've mentioned in the question for both Job and HrRegistrations and passing the same value as required in the api. Please check the question once.

Comment: @AvinashKumar ok then tell me when you post data for job posting information did you also post ```HrRegistration``` information alongside?

Comment: And tell me what did you exactly input (json) in postman for that just update your question.

Comment: I'm posting only the data for the fields i've defined in the JobPosting table. {
    "HrId":"4",
    "Title":"First",
    "Experience":"2",
    "Position":"Software Developer",
    "Company":"ABC",
    "Ctc":"10",
    "Description":"Test"
}
these are the data I'm posting.
there is already one record i'm having as same hrid i've mentioned above in the hrregistrations table.

Comment: @AvinashKumar Ok then debug the code and tell me where you found error. you also passing hrid so i guess given solution should work. and one thing, I did not found any kind of screenshot of your error.

Comment: I've tried debugging, even tried to put the whole code in try catch block, but only this error is coming. Not sure, Please guide

Comment: @AvinashKumar give me a screenshot of your error for better understading.

Comment: Do you familiar with teamviewer? i will connect.

Comment: I've added the latest screen shot of the postman in the question.

Comment: @AvinashKumar Check Mail.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to add a foreign key to a table. I've added the required
> columns, but I'm getting an error when I'm trying to pass the value
> into the table using PostMan.

Actually, based on your shared code snippte and description you are getting the expected error because as per your JobPosting POCO defination its appeared that although your `int? HrId` is nullable but your  `HrRegistration HR` doesn't and the problem arised here.

**Why you cannot insert JobPosting:**

In your reequst you are passing object from post man as following:

```
{
  
  "title": "Some Title",
  "experience": 5,
  "hrId": 5,
  ....// Some more property
}
```

However, according to your table defination,  `HrRegistration HR` is not null and its expecting the object as well. Hence, your request format has changed to  this:

```
{
  "jobId": 0,
  "title": "Test Job Title",
  "experience": 5,
  "hrId": 5,
  ..../ More Property
  "hr": {
    "id": 0,
    "firstName": "string",
    "lastName": "string",
    ..../ More Property
  }
}
```

Consequently, you are getting following error:

[image]

**How to resolve:**

If you want to pass only `JobPosting` POCO object then you can define your `HrRegistration? HR` table as nullable which is equivalent to [WithOptional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/relationships#configuring-a-required-to-optional-relationship-one-tozero-or-one) of fluent api to make the Required-to-Optional Relationship.  just as following which would resolve the error and data will be inserted accordingly:

```
public class JobPosting
    {
        [Key]
        public int JobId { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public int Experience { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("HR")]
        public int? HrId { get; set; }
        public virtual HrRegistration? HR { get; set; }
        .... // More Property

    }
```

**Output:**

[image]

**Note:** If you would like to know more details on [Required-to-Optional Relationship](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/relationships#configuring-a-required-to-optional-relationship-one-tozero-or-one) you could [check our official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/relationships#configuring-a-required-to-optional-relationship-one-tozero-or-one).

Comment: Thank you for your detailed suggestion. I'll definitely try this and will update you with my result.

Comment: If I wanted to pass the same value using Angular Form then how should I do it? Like the value i'm passing through postman, I wanted the user should pass these using the Angular form, Can you please help me achieve this also?

Comment: Stackoverflow convension is, if current solution resolve your issue accept it and then ask new question.